# Windows 8 APP, changing text of a XAML textbox with databinding... game loop worker thread causing issue

Tags: c++, xaml, threadpool

I have created a new project using Direct3D using XAML (so I can have adverts in the end)...

I have a textblock and have Binding on it to a property in a viewmodel.

```
<SwapChainPanel x:Name="swapChainPanel">
    <TextBlock x:Name="debugText"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,658,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Debug}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</SwapChainPanel>
```

If I am inside my XAML.cpp file, and change the property value to something, all is okay...

```
this->DataContext = m_deviceResources->directXPageViewModel;

m_deviceResources->directXPageViewModel->Debug = "YUMMY";
m_deviceResources->directXPageViewModel->Update( ); // runs property changed notifier
```

If I go and change the property from within my game loop, the screen goes blank and it throws no evident errors?

```
// So the same code as above (without this->Datacontext) placed inside my game class.
```

This seems to be because the game class render loop is inside a worker thread:

```
// If the animation render loop is already running then do not start another thread.
if (m_renderLoopWorker != nullptr && m_renderLoopWorker->Status == AsyncStatus::Started)
{
    return;
}

// Create a task that will be run on a background thread.

//IF I PLACE THE CODE HERE, IT WORKS FINE
auto workItemHandler = ref new WorkItemHandler([this](IAsyncAction ^ action)
{   
    // BUT IF HERE, IT SHOWS BLACK SCREEN AND STOPS LOOPING
    m_deviceResources->directXPageViewModel->Debug = "YUMMY";
    m_deviceResources->directXPageViewModel->Update( );

    // Calculate the updated frame and render once per vertical blanking interval.
    while (action->Status == AsyncStatus::Started)
    {
        critical_section::scoped_lock lock(m_criticalSection);
        Update(); // I'D REALLY LIKE TO PUT THE CODE IN HERE
        if (Render())
        {
            m_deviceResources->Present( );
        }
    }
});

// Run task on a dedicated high priority background thread.
m_renderLoopWorker = ThreadPool::RunAsync(workItemHandler, WorkItemPriority::High, WorkItemOptions::TimeSliced);
```

How do I call an update function every loop when I need to be in the correct thread (I guess)

**EDIT:::::::::::::::::::::::::**

My code now looks like this

```
// Create a task that will be run on a background thread.
auto workItemHandler = ref new WorkItemHandler([this](IAsyncAction ^ action)
{


    // Calculate the updated frame and render once per vertical blanking interval.
    while (action->Status == AsyncStatus::Started)
    {
        critical_section::scoped_lock lock(m_criticalSection);
        Update( );


        // THIS IS THE NEW CALL BUT IT CRASHES MY GAME :)
        CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread( )->Dispatcher->RunAsync( CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler( [ this ]( )
        {
            m_deviceResources->directXPageViewModel->Debug = "YUMMY";
            m_deviceResources->directXPageViewModel->Update( );
        } ) );

        if (Render())
        {
            m_deviceResources->Present( );
        }
    }
});
```

This is having some issues and it's hard to find out what exactly is going on.. I think that the CoreDispatcher is NULL or something so it's crashing:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00BB84C7 in Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

**directXPageViewModel.h**

Comment: You should use a view-model - bind the `Text` property to a string property there.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Yes, I should be able to work up an example in a minute ... there are also examples of this on MSDN.

Comment: Following them now.. although i'm unsure of how to get a handle to my view model class from outside again.. so yes, would love to see your example.

Comment: @McGarnagle - Could you direct me to the examples you had in mind? The problem I think I'm having is that the game loop is outside of the pages code behind and I'm not sure how to update some bound variable from that game loop and then have it reflect in the page.

Comment: I used this example as a model in my project.  You should be able to have a view-model class inheriting "BindableBase", and update its properties as needed. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Metro-style-DirectX-18f98448

Comment: Thanks for the tip McGarnagle, I feel very close now... So I have my property being updated and then I run a propertychanged function on my property too... but I still get the same result as above. Do I need to do any special thing to tell my viewmodel that it is in charge of the page.. or is it that just by declaring the correct property name, it will know? Coz the screen goes blank again.

Comment: I figured out that whenever the property value is changed and the propertystatechanged is run, it prevents the render loop from carrying on.. so close now

Comment: I have updated the OP to reflect my new findings

Comment: Ah … I should have known something else was up.  Alin's answer looks on the right track, to me.  I'm not all that knowledgeable about C++ apps, but with C#, you can't modify UI-bound objects from a background thread, you have to dispatch those changes back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CoreDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) class. You should place your code that updates the UI in a lambda and then pass that lambda to the RunAsync method of the dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks going to look as soon as I get home... I have to admit, I'm pretty excited about getting this to work. #glimmerofhope

Comment: So can you help me with my example here... i'm struggling to get this to work.

Comment: I've changed my OP to show you what I've managed to get to compile

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT. Just had to put a CoreWindow^ coreWindow in my resources and use that within my newly issued thread. you legend!